# how to get rid of newline space while using substring_index

Tags: mysql, sql, json

i have a field with value like below:

```
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
id: "805265"
plan: initial
acc: "123456"
last: "1234"
doc: "1281468479"
validation: field
commit: Accept
```

i used below query to extract acc value

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnname, 'acc: "', -1),'last',1) as acc from table_name;
```

i am able to retrieve acc value but problem is when i export the result to csv file, the field is taking newline space which is before last...how do i get rid of that space???

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby? Are you using ActiveRecord? Can you provide some code?

Comment: this is a json field and there is nothing to do with code.i just need to extract the accnum field value....@MarkThomas

Comment: You don't want to extract using AR? Then you should remove the ruby and Rails tags, and perhaps add JSON and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect you would want to strip out the end quote as well. But to answer your specific question, you can just update your `SUBSTRING_INDEX` delimiter to include the newline, i.e. `select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnname, 'acc: "', -1),'\nlast',1) as acc from table_name;`.

Or, if you prefer, you can use the `REPLACE` function to strip out any unwanted characters.